# Edit json object by lua script in redis

Tags: json, lua, redis

I want edit my json object before back from the Redis server,
 In my Redis server I have 4 keys:

```
user:1 {"Id":"1","Name":"Gholzam","Posts":"[]"}
user:1:post:1 {"PostId":"1","Content":"Test content"}
user:1:post:2 {"PostId":"2","Content":"Test content"}
user:1:post:3 {"PostId":"3","Content":"Test content"}
```

I want to get this context by lua script,How ? :

```
{"Id":"1","Name":"Gholzam","Posts":"[{"PostId":"1","Content":"Test
content"},{"PostId":"1","Content":"Test
content"},{"PostId":"1","Content":"Test content"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of client here is largely irrelevant; the important thing to do is: figure out the data storage. You say you have 4 keys - but it is not obvious to me how we we know, given `user:1`, what the posts are. Common approaches there include:

- have a *set* called `user:1:posts` (or something similar) which contains either the full keys (`user:1:post:1`, etc) or the relative keys (`1`, etc)
- have a *hash* called `user:1:posts` (or something similar) which contains the posts keyed by their id

I'd be tempted to use the latter approach, as it is more direct - so I might have:

- `user:1`, a string with contents `{"Id":"1","Name":"Gholzam","Posts":"[]"}`
- `user:1:posts`, a hash with 3 pairs:

  - key `1` with value `{"PostId":"1","Content":"Test content"}`
  - key `2` with value `{"PostId":"2","Content":"Test content"}`
  - key `3` with value `{"PostId":"3","Content":"Test content"}`

Then you can use `hgetall` or `hvals` to get the posts easily.

The second part is how to manipulate json at the server. The good news here is that redis provides access to json tools inside lua via [`cjson`](http://kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson.php).

I am an expert in neither `cjson` nor lua; however, frankly my advice is: *don't* do this. IMO, redis works best if you let it focus on what it is great at: storage and retrieval. You probably *can* bend it to your whim, but I would be very tempted to do any json manipulation **outside** of redis.